# CKEditor 4. Shrinking of text selection

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I select some text and click on toolbar's item (dropdown, image gallery etc)  selection start shrinking

normal behavior
http://prntscr.com/iab12k

and afterward
http://prntscr.com/iab1qk

I tried to catch "selectionChange" event but it's not called when selection shrinking

PS: I found the issue. When SCAYT plugin (when it checking words for correctness)  works, it's happening

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported issue is a known SCAYT issue. Shrinking of text selection is a visual effect only - your text remains be selected. So the issue isn't influenced SCAYT or CKEditor work and doesn't corrupt your content, formatting etc.